# Vim - How do I detect that the buffer is loaded in the quickfix window?

Tags: vim, vimrc, buffer

Various plugins that I use load their own results into a buffer in the quickfix window. For example, [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) loads it's search results there.

I would like to turn off various things like spell checking and the 80 column line indicator when buffers are loaded into the quickfix window.

How do I detect that the buffer is loaded in the quickfix window?

**UPDATE**

I have this so far, which turns off the 80 column marker for quickfix windows.

`au BufReadPost quickfix setlocal colorcolumn=0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim also sets the `'filetype'` to `qf` for the quickfix buffer. Therefore, you can put your customizations into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/qf.vim` (assuming you have `:filetype plugin on`), and it will be sourced automatically.

If you need different settings depending on which command (e.g. `:make` vs `:grep`) created the quickfix contents, you can alternatively hook into the `QuickFixCmdPost` event with an `:autocmd`.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up going for this: au BufReadPost quickfix setlocal colorcolumn=0 which seems to work great. Thanks :)